# Keras seed does not augment images and masks the same

Tags: keras

I'm trying to transform my images and mask labels in sync, but the random augmentations are applied differently to both generators (proven when I save both images to a directory).

I've tried

- seeding all generators in my library stack
- disabling shuffle and multiprocessing
- ensuring augmentation options are identical between images and masks

One thing that did work was setting batch size to 1, but then my training performance suffered.

```
seed_val=0

data_gen_args = dict(
    rescale=1./255,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    validation_split=validation_split)

image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
mask_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)

image_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/x/train_images/',
    target_size=(224, 224),
    color_mode='rgb',
    class_mode=None,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    subset='training',
    save_to_dir='tmp/img/',
    seed=seed_val)

mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/x/train_annotations/',
    target_size=(224, 224),
    color_mode='grayscale',
    class_mode=None,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    subset='training',
    save_to_dir='tmp/mask/',
    seed=seed_val)

train_generator = zip((image_generator), (mask_generator))
```

Answer (score 0):

try setting `shuffle` to `False` to both image and mask

```
image_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/x/train_images/',
    target_size=(224, 224),
    shuffle = False,
    color_mode='rgb',
    class_mode=None,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    subset='training',
    save_to_dir='tmp/img/',
    seed=seed_val)

mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/x/train_annotations/',
    target_size=(224, 224),
    shuffle = False,
    color_mode='grayscale',
    class_mode=None,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    subset='training',
    save_to_dir='tmp/mask/',
    seed=seed_val)
```

Comment: Unfortunately didn't make a difference, appreciate the suggestion though.

Comment: maybe you have to build your own generator

Comment: You're right, I may have to in the future regardless for more features. I just wanted to clarify why my code doesn't work while following the keras documentation before I go down that road.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem that my augmentations for the images and masks weren't in the same order, e.g.

```
img: pan, increase brightness, transform, rgbshift
mask: pan, transform
```

With that, "increase brightness" changes the value from the seed. Should be

```
img: pan, transform, increase brightness, rgbshift 
mask: pan, transform
```